# Strange behaviour with for loop and size_t

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, size-t

```
 size_t size = sizeof(int);
 printf("%d\n", size);

 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d ", i);
 }
```

The above code (using gcc) outptus

4

0 1 2 3

```
 size_t size = sizeof(int);
 printf("%d\n", size);

 int i;
 for (i = -1; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d ", i);
 }
```

This code (i is initialized to -1) outputs only 4 and nothing in the loop.

```
 size_t size = sizeof(int);
 printf("%d\n", size);

 int i;
 for (i = -1; i < (int) size; i++) {
    printf("%d ", i);
 }
```

Adding a cast makes the code run fine again. The output is

4

-1 0 1 2 3

What's going wrong in the second code? Why doesn't printf go wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
i < size
```

When `i` is signed and `size` is unsigned, then `i` is converted to unsigned before the comparison is performed.  This is part of what are called the usual arithmetic conversions.

When `-1` is converted to an unsigned type, the result is the largest possible value representable by the unsigned type, thus `i < size` is false when `i` is `-1` for any value of `size`.

When you use `i < (int)size` instead, both operands of `<` are of type `int`, so no conversions need to be performed and since both operands are signed, you get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks. Is this behaviour general - The lhs being casted to the type of the rhs before comparison?

Comment: No, left or right is not important, some types are just more dominant than others.

Answer (score 0):

size_t is *unsigned*. When you cast size to int, you're casting back to signed, and the comparison works.